# Is there any property of the sigma notation through which we could find 'sigma(i=1 to n) of $i^4$'?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The way we came up with the formulae of similar types like - the summation of cubes of the first 'n' natural numbers proved to be a cumbersome one while trying the above one.

Comment: This kind of problem can be solved more easily with [discrete calculus](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/DCalc.pdf).

Comment: Recall that a simple way to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk$ is to start from $$n^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n(k^2-(k-1)^2)=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)$$ and to deduce that $$2\sum_{k=1}^nk=n^2+\sum_{k=1}^n1=n^2+n.$$ Likewise, to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^3$, assuming that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk$, and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1$ (!) are known, use $$n^4=\sum_{k=1}^nk^4-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^4=\sum_{k=1}^n(k^4-(k-1)^4)=\sum_{k=1}^n(4k^3-6k^2+4k-1)$$ and to deduce that $$4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=n^4+6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-4\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1=\ldots$$

Comment: Likewise to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this PDF on discrete calculus](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/DCalc.pdf). Now, we want to find the discrete integral of $x^4$. First, subtract $x^{\underline 4}$, so we get:
$$x^4=x^{\underline 4}+6x^3-11x^2+6x$$
Now, we have a cubic with leading coefficient $6$, so subtract $6x^{\underline 3}$:
$$x^4=x^{\underline 4}+6x^{\underline 3}+7x^2-6x$$
Now, we have a quadratic with leading coefficient $7$, so subtract $7x^{\underline 2}$:
$$x^4=x^{\underline 4}+6x^{\underline 3}+7x^{\underline 2}+x$$
Now, $x=x^{\underline 1}$:
$$x^4=x^{\underline 4}+6x^{\underline 3}+7x^{\underline 2}+x^{\underline 1}$$
Finally, we can take the discrete integral of both sides from $1$ to $n$:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} x^4=\frac{n^{\underline 5}-1^{\underline 5}}{5}+6\frac{n^{\underline 4}-1^{\underline 4}}{4}+7\frac{n^{\underline 3}-1^{\underline 3}}{3}+\frac{n^{\underline 2}-1^{\underline 2}}{2}$$
I'll let you simplify the rest. Good luck!